# Algorithm for regularizing or normalizing a polygon which is supposed to be rectangular

Tags: geometry, polygon

My app captures the shape of a room by having the user point a camera at floor corners, and then doing a bunch of math, eventually ending up with a polygon.

The assumption is that the walls are straight (not curved). The majority of the corners are formed by walls at right angles to each other, but in some cases might not be.

Depending on how accurately the user points the camera, the (x,y) coordinates I derive for the corner might be beyond the actual corner, or in front of the actual camera, or, less likely, to the left or right. Obviously, in this case, when I connect the dots, I get weird parallelogram or rhomboid shapes. See example.

I am looking for a program or algorithm to normalize or regularize these shapes, provided we know which corners are supposed to be right angles.

My initial attempt involved finding segments which had angles which were "close" to each other, adjust them all to the same angle, and then recalculate the vertices. However, this algorithm proved to be unstable.

My current thinking is to find angles which are most obtuse (as would be caused by a point mistakenly placed beyond the actual corner), or most acute (as would be caused by a point mistakenly placed in front of the actual corner), and find the corner point which would make it a right angle. The problem, however, is that such as adjustment could have side-effects on other corners, such as making them even further away from right angles. I sense I need some kind of algorithm which takes all the information and optimizes/solves it at once--is this a kind of linear programming problem?--but I am stuck.

[image]

Comment: "*The assumption is that the walls are straight (not curved).* " Probably, but you never know. "*The majority of the corners are formed by walls at right angles to each other*" Less probably. Rooms buiding is not rocket science.

Comment: @Ripi2 Thanks for your comment, but I was not making a generalized statement about the nature of architecture. I was setting the conditions for solving this particular problem. In other words, for the time being at least, it is entirely adequate that any solution deal with straight walls, and corners that are at right angles.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a unique solution.

For example, take the perpendicular from the middle point of an edge to the two neighboring edges. This will give you two new corners.

Or take the perpendicular from the end point of an edge to other edges.

Or compute the average of angles in the end points of an edge. Use this average and the middle point of the edge to compute new corners.

Or...

To get the most faithful compliance, capture (or calculate) distances from each corner to the other three. Build triangles with those distances. Then use the average of the coordinates you compute for a corner from 2 or 3 triangles.

Resulting angles will not be exactly 90 degrees, but the polygon will represent the room fairly.